# 301 Redirects with S3

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3

I am trying to replace a few Redirects that are currently located in a .htaccess file to an S3 bucket(s). I am having trouble with the custom redirects to a different domain.

For example, one of my re-directs looks like this:

Redirect 301 /site https://newwebsite.com

I have set the custom routing rule as, but its not doing the redirect, its just replacing "site" with "https://newwebsite.com", ie bucket-name-amazonaws.com/https://newwebsite.com

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals>site</KeyPrefixEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <HostName>newwebsite</HostName>
            <Protocol>https</Protocol>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith></ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Comment: That really should work, and if configured as you describe gives the behavior you observe, it's troubling -- it seems like a bug or regression in S3 itself, which is unlikely but not impossible.  Does substituting `<ReplaceKeyWith></ReplaceKeyWith>` (instead of "Prefix") work?

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either. I have a ticket logged with AWS support, interested to see what's up.

Comment: It will be interesting to see what they say.

Comment: It was user error......I had set it up wrong initially and my browser cached it. I cleared my cache and it works great!

Comment: Or it could be that.  D'oh.

Answer (score 0):

User error....I had initially set it up wrong and it was cached.